# Asymptotic behavior (big O) of a function involving a nonsolvable integral

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Is it possible to find the order of magnitude of a function
$$f(n) = \log \int_{\mathbb{R}}  \frac{1}{(n+e^x)^{n}}g(x)\, dx$$
as $n\in\mathbb{N}$ goes to $+\infty$?

Here $g(x)$ is some function of $x$, not involving $n$, that can not be integrated analytically.
What I do not understand is if it possible to understand the limiting behavior even if the integral can not be computed.

Comment: I forgot to say that the definite integral is finite.

Answer (score 0):

If $(n + e^x)^{-n} g(x)$ is absolutely integrable for some positive value of $n$, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^n \int_{\mathbb R} (n + e^x)^{-n} g(x) dx =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R}
 \left( 1 + \frac {e^x} n \right)^{-n} g(x) dx =
\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-e^x} g(x) dx.$$

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. My question is not really about the "limiting value", but if the integral affects the speed at which the function approaches it.

Comment: If the integral of $e^{-e^x} g(x)$ is not zero, the equation above gives two terms in the expansion of $f(n)$. The leading term doesn't depend on $g$, the constant term and the remainder depend on $g$.